# Type mismatch when converting from a Collection to an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I have a code where I'm adding last rows to collection which should be later transformed to an array and final step is to get last row with the least number of cells in it.

My current code is:

```
Dim lastc, lastc2, lastr, FindColNumber, FindColNumber2 as Long
Dim FindCol as Range
Dim col As New Collection
Dim CollectionToArray As Variant

Set FindCol = 1 'example
FindColNumber = FindCol.Column
lastc = FindColNumber + 1
Set FindCol2 = 5 'example
FindColNumber = FindCol2.Column
lastc2 = FindColNumber - 1
For R = lastc2 To lastc Step -1
lastc2 = R
col.Add Cells(ws.Rows.count, R).End(xlUp).Row
Next R

Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Min(CollectionToArray(col))

Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long

    ReDim result(myCol.count - 1)
    For cnt = 0 To myCol.count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt
    CollectionToArray = result

End Function
```

I am still getting Type Mismatch error and when hovering over CollectionToArray(Col)) I see  "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example please, there are a ton of errors in here beyond the `CollectionToArray(Col)` line you mention in your question body. At a guess, your collection issue is from naming a variable the same thing as a function definition.

Comment: Why did you show us `Set FindCol = 1 'example`. How to set a range, even like an example in this way? Why didn't you use a real range? We could easier be confused by the following code, anyhow... Using `Dim lastc, lastc2, lastr, FindColNumber` declare all the variables as `Variant`. Only `FindColNumber2 as Long` is as `Long`. Then, why to firstly fill a collection and after that fill an array and not directly loading the array in the same iteration? Or without any iteration, knowing the range you try iterating...

Comment: Gotta agree... skip the creation of a collection and create an array directly.